# React How to change an array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
            const Add_Setting = ()=>{ 
            
                const [list, setList] = useState({
                      time : 1,
                      arr1 : [
                         [ {title : 'title1', number : 1},  {title : 'title2', number : 1}],
                         [ {title : 'title1', number : 1},  {title : 'title2', number : 1}]
                      ]
                });
    
    
       const List2 =(props)=>{
           let arr2= list.arr[props.index]["arr2"];
           let list2 = arr2.map((e, i)=>(

        // i want change title and number

                <input type="text" value={e.title}>
                <input type="number" value={e.number}>
           ))
           return list2;
         }
        
        const List = ()=>{
        let list = list.arr.map((e, i)=>(
          <div>
          <List2 index={i}/>
        </div>
        ))
        return list;
        }
        
             return(
                 <div>
                     <List />
                 </div>
              )
          }
```

Hello brother!

I want to change the array in the array,

BUT, Input is refreshed and only one character is input

Is there a way?

Genius friends

If possible, please let me know with error-free code!

Comment: The syntax of the code is messed up. It won't even pass the syntax check and definitely not gonna run. Could you please clean it up a bit?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're trying to accomplish here; but in general, you want the array to drive the output—said differently, make an array with everything you need before you return JSX from your component.

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm still a beginner so I'm studying
I will study and secure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
const Add_Setting = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState({
    time: 1,
    arr: [
      [{ title: 'title1', number: 1 }, { title: 'title2', number: 1 }],
      [{ title: 'title1', number: 1 }, { title: 'title2', number: 1 }],
    ],
  });

  const onChange = (e, primaryIndex, secondaryIndex) => {
    setList((oldList) => {
      const newArr = [...oldList.arr];
      newArr[primaryIndex][secondaryIndex].number = e.target.value;
      return {
        ...oldList,
        arr: newArr,
      };
    });
  };

  const List2 = ({ index: primaryIndex }) => list.arr[primaryIndex].map((e, secondaryIndex) => (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={e.title} />
      <input type="number" value={e.number} onChange={(ev) => onChange.bind(null, ev, primaryIndex, secondaryIndex)} />
    </>
  ));

  const List = () => list.arr.map((_, i) => (
    <div>
      <List2 index={i} />
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <List />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still a beginner student, so I don't know.
Thank you very much. I will study hard in the future.
Thank you so much.
Have a good day~